# Numbering slides in Beamer

Tags: beamer

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\title{Project 1} 
\author{John Smith}            
\institute{Supervisors: Prof A, Prof B}    


\date{\today}                
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}              
\section[Outline]{}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Slide 1}   

\begin{itemize}   


\item 
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Slide 2}   

\begin{itemize}   


\item 
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I have a very simple question: how do I make the numbering appear on the remaining slides?-presently its only appearing on page 2.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the frame option `[plain]`. It is cleaning all the formating stuffs.

Comment: @Sigur, thanks for that. How do I remove the contents list (usually on top of each slide) from every single slide without affecting the numbering?-in other words, how can I replicate what the [plain] command does on each slide?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply remove the `plain` option for the frames in which you want numeration. To suppress the headline, redefine the template to be empty:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\title{Project 1} 
\author{John Smith}            
\institute{Supervisors: Prof A, Prof B}    
\date{\today}                

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}              

\section[Outline]{}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 1}   
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 1}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```